# How can I remove the grid line in the background of the line chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am working on a React JS project. In my project, I need to create line chart components. I am trying to use [Chart JS 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) library for React JS. But, now I am having a little problem customising the line chart. I want to remove the grids and the lines in the background (screenshot) and the label at the top of the chart (My first dataset).

[image]

This is my code.

```
const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        fill: true,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: '#edfce9',
        borderColor: '#3DAA1D',
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: '#3DAA1D',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#3DAA1D',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        showLine: true
      }
    ]
  };

 <Line data={data} />
```

How can I do that? Removing the grids (lines) in the background of the chart and removing the label at the top (My First dataset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation. You can disable gridlines in the options (which you will have to add)
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    ],
    xAxes: [
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    ]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

**V3:**

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false      
      }
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, now I can remove the gridlines. Is it possible to remove the label at the top?

Comment: Please go to the docs first for any questions you have next because its pretty clear (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html), edited example with how you need to remove it

Comment: Got it. All sorted. Thanks.

Comment: I was going through the documentation, for the Doughnut chart, I cannot set the size of the pie, I mean, the width of the circular line. I set weight, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to remove the grids (lines) in the background of the chart in version 4 (Time Cartisian axis):

```
scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'time',
          time: {
              displayFormats: {
                month: 'dd MMM yy'
              },

              unit: 'day'
            },
            
            ticks: {
              color: "black",
                            
            },
           
            **grid {
              DrawOnChartArea : false
            }**,
            
          },

        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            position:'left'
            ticks: {
              color: "black"
                   },
            grid:{
            display = false
                }
          }
     }
```